# How to make a MediaMonkey decode .MOV files?

Tags: windows, quicktime, mediamonkey

I did search the MediaMonkey forum and didn't get any answer.

I installed MediaMonkey and QuickTime. Everything works except `.mov` files.  I installed K Lite 32-bit and 64-bit, but that did not not work. I did a lot of trial and error with installing/un-installing K Lite 32 / K Lite64 / QuickTime. Nothing worked.

I guess if I can somehow make MediaMonkey pick up the right MOV decoder, it will work.  In that case, where do I get a decoder from?

Can I copy the DLLs from `C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\Plugins` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MediaMonkey\Plugins`? Or is there any other place I can get `.mov` DLLs from?

Comment: Have you tried K-Lite *Mega* Codec Pack?

Comment: Yes.  Did not work.

Comment: Is paid solution ok then? http://www.mediamonkey.com/addons/browse/codecs-input-plug-ins/ I seriously find it weird those plug-ins aren't for free. FYI with K Lite mega codec pack installed, Media Player Classic, Windows Media Player and Windows Media Center could play any codec I can throw to it.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Thanks.  I did try that too - the trial version.  Even that did not work.  Like you said, with klite things should have worked, it did not.  Issue is only with mediamonkey - all other software's like media player etc work.  Only mediamonkeys mov has a problem.  I have stopped using mediamonkey.  Have found a  temporary solution.

Comment: Ah, okay then. Can you please tell me why you need media monkey in the first place? I hope your temporary solution can cover your need for now